# What's a common interjection for the reaction to something creepy and disgusting (like some insects or spooky places, etc.)?

Tags: single-word-requests, interjections

For example,

A: - Look! There is a centipede on the table!

B: - (interjection)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A:  I woke up to find a centipede in my hair.  (creepy / frightening )

B:  Yikes!

A:  I had almost finished my salad when a centipede crawled out from under a lettuce leaf. (disgusting)

B:  Ugh!

Comment: Granted, *"Yikes"* isn't as dated as, for example, *"My word!", or "Golly!". But it's not exactly "current" - I find it hard to imagine anyone using it non-facetiously.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers have mentioned, *eek* (with long E as in "bleak") expresses fright, while *yuck* expresses disgust; I think *ugh* may also be suitable, depending on context: it can express both disgust and contempt.

Comment: +1 for Ugh (that's what I'd say if I saw a centipede on the table)!

Answer (score 3):

*Ew* works in place of *yuck* or *ugh*, especially if the speaker is a child.

Answer (score 2):

Eek!

That's what immediately comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Yuck! There's is a centipede on the table.
>   Yuck will also do as eek.