# How do you write the expression of disgust that sounds like "er"?

Tags: expressions, british-english, orthography, ambiguity, interjections

My daughter said to me this morning (the context is irrelevant):

> Er, it's all wet!

The interjection I have written here as *Er* was synonymous with *Yuck*. Its wetness did not cause great happiness.

But what's the right way to write it? The problem with the way I've formulated it above is that it looks like the *Er* of (genuine or mock) hesitation, synonymous with *Um*. In fact I think that would be as natural a reading of the sentence as the *Yuck* reading. This would significantly change the overall understanding, and change the response from disgust to something like confusion.

I could try *Err*, but I don't think that's any less ambiguous. And of course I could write *Yuck*, which would convey the right sense, but direct quotation ought to respect the original wording.

(I have a feeling that this is a British expression, so I'm tentatively tagging as BrE, but I'm uncertain about this. It's supported by noting that the answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8827/89306) don't mention *Er* at all.)

Comment: American speakers would be rather confused by a spelling with 'R', as the large majority of us are rhotic  speakers.

Comment: @snailboat she pronounced it in a nice rhotic fashion of which most Americans would approve (admittedly only because of the initial vowel in *it's*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional spelling was *Ugh* (or sometimes *Eugh!*) but this may be being supplanted by the American *Eww!* Since the word is near-onomatopeic, I would suggest you write it the way it sounds to you when your daughter says it.

Comment: Thanks. *Ugh* is not pronounced *Er*, though, right? I mean, I sometimes say something that sounds like *Ugh*, and I sometimes say *Er*, but I'd want to distinguish the two.

Comment: *Ugh* is pronounced /ʌg/ by people who don't know that word spells the sound which may be approximated as /ɜ:/ or /ɪɜ:/ or /ɪəχ/ -- for which *yuck* is also an approximation.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, I pronounce it /əχ/, which wasn't on your list, but perhaps was included by implication.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There’s also the spelling *ick* which isn’t so far from the others as one might think.

Answer (score 0):

"Eew!" or "*eww!*", or "*ew!*", is a common expression of disgust. (AmE) "Er", is known more as an expression of uncertainty, or even, apology or regret.

So, "Er, it's all wet," would have a much different meaning to a reader in the US.

"Why aren't you wearing the new necktie I got you for the party tonight?"

"Er, it's all wet. It fell into the sink while (or basin/whilst) I was shaving."

"Here, let me see... *Ew!*"

Comment: Right, that's what I suspected. In BrE, *Er* (or the sound that fits that spelling, at any rate) is ambiguous between your *Ew* and your *Er*.

Answer (score -2):

In British English, written 'ugh' is pronounced 'er'

Comment: *ugh* is pronouced [/ʊh/, /ʌh/, /əː/, /ʊx/ or /ʌɡ/](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ugh).